# Android Service calling itself again 1 minute later

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I'm trying to make a Service, wake up and call itself again after one minute (in this example, I know its bad for battery).

Here is part of the code:

```
public class SpeechService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        setUpNextAlarm();
    }

    public void setUpNextAlarm(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(SpeechService.this, this.getClass());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long nextUpdateTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis + 1 * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;

        // Schedule the alarm!
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)ContextManager.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,nextUpdateTimeMillis, pendingIntent);
        Log.e("test","I am back!");
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        Log.e("test","I am back!");
        setUpNextAlarm();
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm calling setUpNextAlarm on service create, I see the log at the end, but then the service is never being called again. I have tried this in an IndentService, it works but I need it to work in a normal Service :(.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using a Service and an IntentService. The IntentService was using the AlarmManager and then it was calling the Service.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 PendingIntent.getService
```

not

```
 PendingIntent.getBroadcast
```

You are getting a Broadcast Intent.

Comment: I think you should call super.oncreate in your on create function. Also I think you better use intentservice, its easier to manage

Comment: oh sorry I do have the super.onCreate(); in the create function, I just removed some useless code to make it simpler but I removed this by mistake